# Promise data when using react and axios

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, promise, axios

in this code whenever I try to direct to **/dashboard** it wouldn't wait for the response of axios and goes immediately to **return** part and it use `loggedin` with it's default value which is `undefined` here. Well I guess I should use promises but I don't know how...
So I would appreciate it if someone could help.

````
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import OverallCondition from "./dashOverall";
import Toolbar from "./dashToolbar";

export default function Dashboard(){
    const [loggedin, check] = useState()
    axios.get('/loggedin')
        .then(response => {
            check(response.data)
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    return <section className='dashboard'>
            {loggedin ? <div>
                <Toolbar/>
                <OverallCondition/>
            </div> : <Redirect to='/login'/>}
    </section>
}```
````

Comment: You should make this route protected, before rendering this component check whether user is logged in or not. You are checking user is logged in or not while rendering this component which is problem itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `useEffect` hook to make the HTTP request.

Making the HTTP request at the top-level inside your function component will trigger a new HTTP request every time your component is re-rendered.

Also, since the `axios.get(...)` is asynchronous, code *below* the `axios.get(...)` will execute *before* the request is completed.

To handle this situation appropriately, follow the steps mentioned below:

1. Create a state that represents whether the HTTP request is pending or not. Its initial value should be true

   ```
   const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
   ```
2. Use the `useEffect` hook to make the HTTP request. Making HTTP requests at the top-level inside the function component is NOT the right approach - you don't want to make a request every time your component re-renders

   Also don't forget to set `isPending` to `false`, otherwise user will continue to see the loading spinner even after the request has completed. You can use the `finally()` method to call `setIsPending(false)`

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('/loggedin')
       .then(response => setLoggedIn(response.data))
       .catch(err => console.error(err))
       .finally(() => setIsPending(false));
   }, []);
   ```

   Empty array passes as a second argument to the `useEffect` hook will ensure that the HTTP request is initiated only once, after the initial render of the component
3. While the request is pending, show some loading spinner to the user. When the component first renders, as the `isPending` is true, user will see the loading spinner

   ```
   if (isPending) {
      return <Spinner/>;  // you need to create the "Spinner" component
   }
   ```

Here's how you could implement the above steps in your code:

```
function Dashboard() {
    const [loggedin, setLoggedIn] = useState();

    // this state will be used to show a loading spinner
    const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);

    // for HTTP request, use the "useEffect" hook
    useEffect(() => {
       axios.get('/loggedin')
        .then(response => setLoggedIn(response.data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
        .finally(() => setIsPending(false));
    }, []);

    // show a spinner to the user while HTTP 
    // request is pending
    if (isPending) {
       return <Spinner/>;  
    }
    
    return (
       <section className='dashboard'>
          {loggedin ? (
                <div>
                  <Toolbar/>
                  <OverallCondition/>
                </div> 
              ) : <Redirect to='/login'/>
           }
       </section>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues with the code

### Use a better terminology with the useState return

Instead of

```
const [loggedin, check] = useState()
```

Use

```
const [loggedin, setLoggedin] = useState()
```

### Understand the life cycle

Your axios.get is inside the function body, all code there will be executed on every render, it is certainly not what you wanted, for operations that may have side effects, you need to use the useEffect hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

The useEffect hook allows you to control better when the code will execute, in your case, you want it to run once

```
const ShowOnceLoaded = ({ isLoaded, children }) => {
   if (!isLoaded)
     return <p>Loading...</p>

   return <>{children}</>
}

export default function Dashboard(){
    const [ isLoaded, setIsLoaded ] = useState(false)
    const [loggedin, setLoggedin] = useState(false)

    React.useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('/loggedin')
        .then(response => {
            setLoggedin(true)
            setIsLoaded(true)
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }, [])
    
    return <section className='dashboard'>
            <ShowOnceLoaded isLoaded={isLoaded}>
            {loggedin ? <div>
                <Toolbar/>
                <OverallCondition/>
            </div> : <Redirect to='/login'/>}
            </ShowOnceLoaded>
    </section>
}
```

In addition to what you had, now there is a state set once the request is complete, only then we can decide if the user is logged in or not, otherwise, we will redirect the user even before the request is done, as the state initializes as false by default

The empty array on useEffect is used to run the code only when the component mounts